Is there any way to go about recovering Solana stolen through phantom
On July 20th, a transaction was signed authorizing the transfer of exactly 44 Solana from my wallet (HcYw37YxybjT29DBofzwAtj6o9gViSzPCcisgCJA72sd) to another wallet (7d9gJxcF3no4yycPvnrSZ4S93KswfRHtiGcTqkk4Q9sN). It is worth noting that at the time of this occurrence, I had not signed any transactions at all, as I infrequently use the browser with the extension, with proof that I had not even opened the browser since July 13th.After further investigating the wallet the funds had been sent to, I had recognized it being set a few times to different wallets and converted into USDC. I had not authorized this at all, and had never provided the signature for this at all, meaning I was blatantly robbed for the money. There was no compromise to my physical laptop, and nobody has access to my keys, so I am not sure what even happened here. Devastated.

Sorry to hear about that but Solana's security model relies on the principle that only the holder of the private key can sign transactions therefore if this transfer was made it is safe to say your private key has been compromised one way or the other. My advice would be to secure your wallet immediately
Move any remaining funds to a new wallet immediately. Make sure to generate new private keys and do not reuse the compromised keys.
